# Java pattern expression to exclude a special string

Tags: java, regex

All , Source content may like this :

```
String content1 = "url:(\"../../aaa/bbb/ccc\")";
String content2 = "url:('/bb/add/www')";
String content3 = "url:(ggg/eee/xxx)";
String content4 = "url:('../../aaa/bbb/ccc')";
```

Who can help me design a high performance Java pattern matcher regex as below:

```
regex = "^[.]*url\\:\\([\"\\'][(?:\\.\\.)?]([^\"\\)]+)[\"\\']\\)$";

public static String parsePath(String content,String regex) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return  matcher.group(1);
    }
    return null;
}
```

I want input such as content1 to content 4 , call parsePath function will always return /aaa/bbb/ccc , /bb/add/www , ggg/eee/xxx, /aaa/bbb/ccc . That is I want to skip the prefix (`"|'..` and postfix `'|"`) and just want to snap the middle actual url path start with / .

So anyone who can help me to write a regex expression with high performance  ?

Comment: Please give examples of what *shouldn't* match. It will help us craft an answer

Comment: Your regex expression must start with `^` and end with `$`. This is required to say that the string must start with... and end with...; otherwise it would match anywhere in the string

Comment: Hi, Bohemian , I want to escape the ".." and "'" , "\"" from the source code .

Comment: All , I edit my requirements , thank you and go on .

Comment: Your string content3 and it's desired output contradicts. Please have a edit on either one of these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally , I try many times and get it worked by designing a pattern expression as below :

```
regex = "url\\([\"\\'][(?:\\.\\.)]*([^\"\\)]+)[\"\\']\\)";
```

Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about a single regex solution, but you can achieve the same in a 2-fold approach :

```
public static String parsePath(String content, String regex) {
    content = content.replaceFirst("^url\\:\\([\"']?([.]{2})?(/[.]{2})*", "");
    // rest is same as previous
    // .......................
}
```

Then use the following in Matcher :

```
  regex = "(^([a-z]+)?(/?[a-z]+)*)(?=[\"']?\\)$)"
```

You may put the regex inside method itself, rather than passing it as a parameter. And  update the character class([a-z]) as per your need.

NOTE : The above solution won't match strings like **"url:(\"../..../aaa/bbb/ccc\")"** or **"url:(\"..../../aaa/bbb/ccc\")"**  or **"url:(\"..///")"** at all, which was not handled by the regex you show in the question and comment.

Comment: Hi, i want to match sample like this , I want to exact extraction like: 
    regex = "^[.]*url\\:\\([\"\\'][(?:\\.\\.)?]([^\"\\)]+)[\"\\']\\)$";

Comment: Hi, Black , Yes ,your solutions will be another good pattern expression for more largely used as another needs .It inspire me a lot actually for how to simple the design and implementation . Thank you .

Comment: Thanks for the appreciation. The main problem using single regex is that positive lookbehind assertion doesn't allow variable length expression(use of * or +).